# How to serialize a form properly with input name array

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form with inputs that look like this:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="location[0]">
    <input type="text" name="location[1]">
    <input type="text" name="user[0]">
    <input type="text" name="user[1]">
    ...
</form>
```

I am making an ajax call with the form data as the post body. When I try to serialize the form (`$("#myForm").serializeArray`), I do not get arrays within an array. I still get all fields as their own separate objects like so:

```
[
 {
    name: "location[0]",
    value: "123"
 },
 {
    name: "location[1]",
    value: "456"
 }
 ...
]
```

How do I serialize the form so that I have a multidimensional array as the data to send to my backend (in Scala)? I want it to look like:

```
[
  { name: "location",
    value: [123, 456]
  },
  { name: "user",
    value: ["Jim", "Jane"]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Remove indexing from input arrays. For example, try <input type="text" name="user[]"> instead of <input type="text" name="user[0]"> and then serialize.

Comment: I tried that, too. It still creates an object for each input. I get an array like this: [ { location[] }, { location[] }, { user[] }, { user[] } ].

Comment: I don't think that is possible or desired: in the serialised form the `value` property value must be a string. You could however go for a CSV string value.

Comment: I don't know about Scala, but other backends (e.g. PHP)  create arrays when they see these multiple `location[]` keys.

Comment: i don't think that javascript can achieve this because the serialized form generally is used to be sent to backend where every single input of that form is important and can't be "compacted" with others, you need to write another function to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w8bu4s10/

I don't know a basic function but you can use this function:

```
function getArray(element){
  var result = new Array();
  $(element).find('input').each(function(i,e){
    // extract path from name
    var path = $(e).attr('name').split('[');
    for(var key in path){
        if(path[key].endsWith(']')){
        path[key] = path[key].substr(0, path[key].length-1);
      }
    }

    // create path inside result array
    var node = result;
    for(var depth in path){
        if(depth == path.length-1){
                if(Number.isInteger(path[depth])){
                    node.splice(path[depth], 0, $(e).val());
        }else{
            node.push($(e).val());
        }
            }else{
        var found = false;
        for(var key in node){
          if(node[key].name == path[depth]){
            found = true;
            node = node[key].value;
            break;
          }
        }

        if(!found){
          var obj = new Object();
          obj['name'] = path[depth];
          obj['value'] = new Array();
          node.push(obj);
          node = node[node.length - 1].value;
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return JSON.stringify(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. Name all inputs with array brackets at the end, but do not specify an index in []. Even though it doesn't look like a proper array value when printing the result of `form.serializeArray()`, the backend will properly interpret it. In my case, Scala Play consolidated all values with the same key into an ArrayBuffer.

Comment: How is that different to what I suggested? See my comment to your original question.

Comment: Your suggestion was right but did not explain that the backend will interpret it properly even though what I saw through console.log was not showing an array.